# Device drivers with same numbers

Tags: devices

```
cat /proc/devices

Character devices:
  1 mem
  4 /dev/vc/0
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
  5 ttyprintk
  6 lp
  7 vcs
 10 misc
 13 input
 21 sg
 29 fb
 89 i2c
 99 ppdev
108 ppp
116 alsa
128 ptm
136 pts
180 usb
189 usb_device
195 nvidia-frontend
226 drm
245 nvidia-uvm
246 nvlink_core
247 mei
248 hidraw
249 bsg
250 watchdog
251 rtc
252 dimmctl
253 ndctl
254 tpm

Block devices:
  1 ramdisk
259 blkext
  7 loop
  8 sd
  9 md
 11 sr
 65 sd
 66 sd
 67 sd
 68 sd
 69 sd
 70 sd
 71 sd
128 sd
129 sd
130 sd
131 sd
132 sd
133 sd
134 sd
135 sd
252 device-mapper
253 virtblk
254 mdp
```

How is it possible to have same numbers for different devices ?
For example: char device "vcs" and block device "loop"

Comment: Does the discussion here help? [Are the major, minor number unique](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124233/65304)